# ¿Cómo calcular logaritmos sin funciones del sistema?

Tags: vb.net

Hoy he rectificado un poco la función para que funcione bien con los logaritmos de base 10, pero sigue igual que antes...

```
Public Function Logaritm(ByVal NumBase As String, ByVal NumLog As String, Optional ByVal ReIterations As Integer = 128) As String
        Logaritm = StringCero
        On Error Resume Next

        ' La Variable Reiterations Se Refiere a Cuantas Veces 
        ' Redunda en la División en Busca de Decimales...

        Dim Cuenta As String = StringCero
        Dim Restante As String = NumLog

        ' Aquí entra Siempre y Cuando NumLog Sea Mayor a NumBase
        Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayor(NumBase, Restante) = True
            ' Primero Voy Haciendo Divisiones Para 
            ' Conseguir la Parte Entera del Logaritmo
            Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)

            Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
        Loop

        ' He Probado Hasta con el Residuo de la 1ª División Que Se Accede Así
        ' Dim Residuo As String = StringCero
        ' Residuo = BigNumbers.MODDivision(NumLog, NumBase, ReIterations)
        ' Pero Sin Exito...

        ' El Código Hasta Aquí Va Bien, Pero 
        ' ¿Cómo Lo Hago Para Tratar con el Residuo Que Queda en Restante?
        ' Lo He Intentado Así

        Dim Resultado As String = Restante ' Aquí Contiene el Residuo del Logaritmo

        If BigNumbers.IsMayor(Restante, StringUno) = True Then
            ' Si entro aquí es que el logaritmo contiene 
            ' Residuo Mayor a Uno Para Que Vayan los Logaritmos de Diez
            Resultado = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
            ' Si el Resultado es un Número Real, Lo Tratas con sus Decimales
            If BigNumbers.IsReal(Resultado) = True Then
                ' PolStrings.StringsRight Coge los Números Decimales Hasta la Coma  
                Resultado = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringCero & StringComa & PolStrings.StringsRight(Resultado))
            Else
                ' Si es Que No los Sumas Tal Cual
                Resultado = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, Resultado)
            End If
        Else
            ' Aquí Entra Cuando Restante es Igual a Uno o Menor
            Resultado = Cuenta
        End If

        ' Y Finalizo con Resultado
        Return Resultado

    End Function
```

Estoy haciendo una calculadora que funciona con sumas, restas, multiplicaciones, divisiones y raíces cuadradas de largadas exageradas y de momento hasta aquí bien...
Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Cómo calcular el residuo de los logaritmos con los operadores (métodos) que ya tengo programados (sumas restas multiplicaciones, divisiones y raíz cuadrada)?.
Estoy haciendo la función de logaritmos de cualquier base y saco los que son enteros correctamente (enteros sin residuo) pero no logro saber como continuarla.
Aquí os muestro mi código hasta aquí:

```
Public Function Logaritm(ByVal NumBase As String, ByVal NumLog As String, Optional ByVal ReIterations As Integer = 128) As String
        Logaritm = StringCero
        On Error Resume Next

        Dim Cuenta As String = StringCero
        Dim Restante As String = NumLog

        Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayor(NumBase, Restante) = True
            ' Primero Voy Haciendo Divisiones Para 
            ' Conseguir la Parte Entera del Logaritmo
            Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
            Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
        Loop

        ' Hasta Aquí Va Bien, Pero ¿Cómo Lo Hago Para Tratar con el Residuo?

        Dim Resultado As String = Cuenta
        If BigNumbers.IsMayor(Restante, StringCero) = True Then
            ' Si entro aquí es que el logaritmo contiene residuo
            Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
            Resultado = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, Restante)
        Else
            Resultado = Cuenta
        End If

        Return Resultado

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función para hacer un Logaritmo de cualquier base es esta:

```
Private Const StringCero As String = "0"
Private Const StringUno As String = "1"
Private Const StringDos As String = "2"
Private Const StringTres As String = "3"
Private Const StringCuatro As String = "4"
Private Const StringCinco As String = "5"
Private Const StringSeis As String = "6"
Private Const StringSiete As String = "7"
Private Const StringOcho As String = "8"
Private Const StringNueve As String = "9"
Private Const StringDiez As String = "10"
Private Const StringCien As String = "100"
Private Const StringMil As String = "1000"

Public Const ConstanteE As String = "2,71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995958"


Public Enum LogaritmNumBase
    NumBase2
    NumBase3
    NumBase4
    NumBase5
    NumBase6
    NumBase8
    NumBase10
    NumBase16
    NumBase100
    NumBase1000
    NumBaseConstantE
    NumBaseNumber2
End Enum

    Public Function Logaritm(ByVal NumLog As String, Optional BaseNum As BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase = BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase10, Optional ByVal ReIterations As Integer = 32, Optional ByVal NumBaseNumber2 As String = StringDos) As String
    Logaritm = StringCero
    On Error Resume Next

    If BigNumbers.IsEqualCero(NumLog) = True Then Exit Function
    If ReIterations < 32 Then ReIterations = 32
    If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(StringUno, NumLog) = True Then Exit Function

    Dim Cuenta As String = StringCero
    Dim Restante As String = NumLog
    Dim NumBase As String = vbNullString
    Dim Resultado As String = vbNullString
    Dim PrimerParametro As String = StringCero

    Select Case BaseNum
        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase2
            NumBase = StringDos

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase3
            NumBase = StringTres

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase4
            NumBase = StringCuatro

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase5
            NumBase = StringCinco

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase6
            NumBase = StringSeis

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase8
            NumBase = StringOcho

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase10
            NumBase = StringDiez

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase16
            NumBase = StringDiezySeis

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase100
            NumBase = StringCien

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase1000
            NumBase = StringMil

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBaseConstantE
            NumBase = ConstanteE

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) = True Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBaseNumber2
            NumBase = NumBaseNumber2

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) = True Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

    End Select


    Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayor(Restante, NumBase) = False
        Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
        Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
    Loop
    PrimerParametro = Cuenta

    Dim SegundoParametro As String = BigNumbers.ElevarPotencia(NumBase, PrimerParametro, ReIterations)
    Dim TercerParametro As String = BigNumbers.ElevarPotencia(NumBase, BigNumbers.Sumar(StringUno, PrimerParametro), ReIterations)

    If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumLog, SegundoParametro) = False And BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumLog, TercerParametro) = False Then

        Dim TempoResta1 As String = BigNumbers.Restar(TercerParametro, SegundoParametro)
        Dim TempoResta2 As String = BigNumbers.Restar(TercerParametro, NumLog)
        Dim TempoResta3 As String = BigNumbers.Divide(TempoResta2, TempoResta1, ReIterations)
        Dim CuartoParametro As String = BigNumbers.Restar(StringUno, TempoResta3)
        Resultado = BigNumbers.Sumar(PrimerParametro, CuartoParametro)

    ElseIf BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumLog, TercerParametro) = True Then
        Resultado = BigNumbers.Sumar(StringUno, PrimerParametro)
    Else
        Resultado = PrimerParametro
    End If


    Return Resultado

End Function
```

Comment: Era cuestión de obtener primero la parte entera de exponente que es llas veces que se divide hasta llegar a numero de base.
Después es cuestión de dos potencias y dos restas con una división y la resta de 1 al resultado.
Y así se obtiene el Logaritmo de cualquier base.

Answer (score 2):

Acabo de resolver uno de los logaritmos, es el neperiano, pero aún tengo por resolver los de 2 3 5 10 100 y 1000 que son los que no encontraba los decimales...
Aún tengo que repasar-la y al final he usado los logaritmos neperianos del sistema en un punto concreto de todas las funciones.

La cosa queda así:

```
Public Function Logaritm(ByVal NumLog As String, Optional BaseNum As BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase = BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase10, Optional ByVal ReIterations As Integer = 32) As String
    Logaritm = StringCero
    On Error Resume Next

    If BigNumbers.IsEqualCero(NumLog) = True Then Exit Function
    If ReIterations < 32 Then ReIterations = 32
    If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(StringUno, NumLog) = True Then Exit Function

    Dim Cuenta As String = StringCero
    Dim Restante As String = NumLog
    Dim NumBase As String = vbNullString
    Dim Resultado As String = vbNullString

    Select Case BaseNum
        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase2
            NumBase = StringDos

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function


            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayorAndEqual(Restante, NumBase) = True
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Restante, NumBase)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Resultado = StringGuion & Cuenta
            Else
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayor(Restante, NumBase) = False
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Resultado = Cuenta
            End If
        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase3
            NumBase = StringTres

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayorAndEqual(Restante, NumBase) = True
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Restante, NumBase)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Resultado = StringGuion & Cuenta
            Else
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayor(Restante, NumBase) = False
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Resultado = Cuenta
            End If

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase5
            NumBase = StringCinco

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayorAndEqual(Restante, NumBase) = True
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Restante, NumBase)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Resultado = StringGuion & Cuenta
            Else
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayor(Restante, NumBase) = False
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Resultado = Cuenta
            End If

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase10
            NumBase = StringDiez


            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Resultado = StringGuion & (BigNumbers.GetNumberDecimals(NumLog) + (Len(NumBase) - Uno))
            Else
                Resultado = ((Len(BigNumbers.GetIntegerPartNumber(NumLog)) - Len(NumBase)) + Uno)
            End If

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase100
            NumBase = StringCien

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Resultado = StringGuion & (((BigNumbers.GetNumberDecimals(NumLog) + Len(NumBase)) \ Dos) - Uno)
            Else
                Resultado = (((Len(BigNumbers.GetIntegerPartNumber(NumLog)) - Len(NumBase)) \ Dos) + Uno)
            End If

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase1000
            NumBase = StringMil

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Resultado = StringGuion & (((BigNumbers.GetNumberDecimals(NumLog) + Len(NumBase)) \ Tres) - Uno)
            Else
                Resultado = (((Len(BigNumbers.GetIntegerPartNumber(NumLog)) - Len(NumBase)) \ Tres) + Uno)
            End If

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBaseNumE
            NumBase = ConstanteE  ' Constante E de 53 Decimales

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) = True Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            Resultado = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Math.Log(CDbl(NumLog)), BigNumbers.Divide(StringUno, Math.Log(CDbl(NumBase)), ReIterations))

    End Select

    Return Resultado
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que estoy viendo, la pregunta la puedo contestar ahora:
Los logaritmos de Diferentes bases se calculan de diferentes formas según su base, así que el método estaba mal enfocado. Ahora he hecho lo Siguiente Separando los tipos de bases que existen y para cada una de ellas he creado sus propios métodos para conseguir los números precisos en cada caso.

Aunque he separado los números de base, ahora sigo sin saber cómo llegar a su parte decimal en los de 2 3 5 y neperiano....

El Método con el que lo he arreglado más o menos es este:

```
Public Function Logaritm(ByVal NumLog As String, Optional BaseNum As BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase = BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase10, Optional ByVal ReIterations As Integer = 128) As String
    Logaritm = StringCero
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Cuenta As String = StringCero
    Dim Restante As String = NumLog
    Dim NumBase As String = vbNullString
    Dim Resultado As String = vbNullString

    Select Case BaseNum
        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase2
            NumBase = StringDos

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayorAndEqual(Restante, NumBase) = True
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Restante, NumBase)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Resultado = StringGuion & Cuenta
            Else

                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayor(Restante, NumBase) = False
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Resultado = Cuenta
            End If
        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase3
            NumBase = StringTres

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayorAndEqual(Restante, NumBase) = True
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Restante, NumBase)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Resultado = StringGuion & Cuenta
            Else

                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayor(Restante, NumBase) = False
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Resultado = Cuenta
            End If

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase5
            NumBase = StringCinco

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayorAndEqual(Restante, NumBase) = True
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Restante, NumBase)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Resultado = StringGuion & Cuenta
            Else

                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayor(Restante, NumBase) = False
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
                    Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Resultado = Cuenta
            End If

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase10
            NumBase = StringDiez


            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Resultado = StringGuion & (BigNumbers.GetNumberDecimals(NumLog) + (Len(NumBase) - Uno))
            Else
                Resultado = ((Len(BigNumbers.GetIntegerPartNumber(NumLog)) - Len(NumBase)) + Uno)
            End If

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase100
            NumBase = StringCien

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Resultado = StringGuion & (((BigNumbers.GetNumberDecimals(NumLog) + Len(NumBase)) \ Dos) - Uno)
            Else
                Resultado = (((Len(BigNumbers.GetIntegerPartNumber(NumLog)) - Len(NumBase)) \ Dos) + Uno)
            End If

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBase1000
            NumBase = StringMil

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Resultado = StringGuion & (((BigNumbers.GetNumberDecimals(NumLog) + Len(NumBase)) \ Tres))
            Else
                Resultado = (((Len(BigNumbers.GetIntegerPartNumber(NumLog)) - Len(NumBase)) \ Tres) + Uno)
            End If

        Case BigNumbers.LogaritmNumBase.NumBaseNumE
            NumBase = ConstanteE

            If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(NumBase, NumLog) Then Return StringUno : Exit Function

            If BigNumbers.IsMayor(NumLog, NumBase) = False Then
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayorAndEqual(Restante, NumBase) = True
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Restante, NumBase)
                    'Cuenta = BigNumbers.Sumar(Cuenta, StringUno)
                Loop
                If BigNumbers.IsReal(Restante) = True Then
                    Resultado = StringGuion & StringCero & StringComa & PolStrings.StringsRight(Restante)
                Else
                    Resultado = StringGuion & Restante
                End If
            Else
                Do Until PolCalculator.IsMayor(Restante, NumBase) = False
                    Restante = BigNumbers.Divide(Restante, NumBase, ReIterations)
                Loop
                Resultado = Restante
            End If

    End Select

    Return Resultado
End Function
```

Comment: Si esto no es una respuesta a tu pregunta, no va acá abajo en la sección de respuestas. El recuadro está titulado Tu Respuesta. Si esto es una aclaración o info adicional de tu pregunta, va en tu pregunta y esta no-respuesta debe borrarase. :)

Comment: Lo dejo abierto porque aún no se cómo conseguir el logaritmo neperiano, no por otra cosa. Esto soluciona parte del tema en cuestión, pero no todo al completo...